# KMeans clustering attempts returning a name not defined error

Tags: python, k-means

Good morning!

I'm working on a lesson to learn kmeans clustering and I've hit a snag and can't understand why.

```
# set number of clusters
kclusters = 5

austin_grouped_clustering = austin_grouped.drop('Borough', 1)

# run k-means clustering
KMeans = KMeans(n_clusters=kclusters, random_state=0).fit(ausitn_grouped_clustering)

# check cluster labels generated for each row in the dataframe
labels = kmeans.labels_[0:10]
```

When setting up and running my kmeans clusters I keep getting an error for "NameError: name 'ausitn_grouped_clustering' is not defined". I can independently run each line of code up to the error, which I thought would define austin_grouped_clustering, but no dice.

Am I not understanding the setup of kmeans in this situation?

Please give me some pointers and advice on how to move forward. Thank you!

BIG EDIT: Austin is misspelled. Working forward.

[Error snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wiYoI.jpg)

Comment: There's a typo in your kmeans fit method. You've written ausitn instead of austin. For future reference, don't name your variables the same as the function you intend to use e.g. use `kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=kclusters, random_state=0).fit(austin_grouped_clustering)` instead of `KMeans = ...`

Comment: @kynnem Thank you! I saw that right before you posted. Corrected it and now am getting a string to float error. Working that one over now.